# Why my form start be blocked after submit in yii2?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I have got the form. It was created with the help of ActiveForm class.
I blocked standard submit with `preventDefault();` method And `afterValidate` the form I submit the form with an AJAX call:

```
$('#form').on('afterValidate', function () {
    var url = $('#form').attr('action');
        var data = $('#form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data
        });
 });
```

All works good. But it only works the first time. The second submit is not working with other data. How I can reset the validation of the form after every submit with AJAX?

Comment: So you need AJAX validation? In this case why not use built-in AJAX validation instead of reimplementing it manually?

Comment: You can use Pjax and reload it in ajax success.

Comment: @arogachev , no, I want to do some magic on 'afterValidate'. But it magic don't work after first submit with ajax. I think, that I need to reset validation, but how?